# genymotion throws libssl_conf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, genymotion

When I execute following code on Kali Linux

```
#/opt/genymobile/genymotion# ./genymotion
```

I get

```
> Logging activities to file: /root/.Genymobile/genymotion.log
Auto configuration failed
139950541100688:error:25066067:DSO support routines:DLFCN_LOAD:could not load the shared library:dso_dlfcn.c:185:filename(libssl_conf.so): libssl_conf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
139950541100688:error:25070067:DSO support routines:DSO_load:could not load the shared library:dso_lib.c:244:
139950541100688:error:0E07506E:configuration file routines:MODULE_LOAD_DSO:error loading dso:conf_mod.c:285:module=ssl_conf, path=ssl_conf
139950541100688:error:0E076071:configuration file routines:MODULE_RUN:unknown module name:conf_mod.c:222:module=ssl_conf
```

But running the command

```
export OPENSSL_CONF=/etc/ssl/
```

solves this problem for that session.

Comment: I have the same problem with phantomjs npm package on Debian. Thanks for `export OPENSSL_CONF=/etc/ssl/` workaround.

Comment: This is not a programming question, it should have been a bug ticket at Debian's instead, along with a reproduction recipe.

Comment: What about running your program with strace -f, grep the output with your lib name and see where it is looking for the lib ?
You could make a symbolic link to the lib where it is needed.

Comment: Most likely a [relevant issue](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/15449).

Answer (score 32):

I think you have the answer just write

```
export OPENSSL_CONF=/etc/ssl/
```

to your .bashrc file and restart your computer
The problem should be permanently solved.

I had a similar issue installing GenomeBrowser on Fedora and this solved it.

you could achieve the above by:

```
echo "export OPENSSL_CONF=/etc/ssl/" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
```

or if you have zsh for your shell you could do this instead:

```
echo "export OPENSSL_CONF=/etc/ssl/" >> ~/.zshrc && source ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: Is this safe, no side effects ?

Comment: Yes it is safe. It just ensures the environment variable persists.

Comment: @SundayIkpe I did the same, back in 2018. :)